# How to make optional word in PEG.js

Tags: javascript, parsing, peg, pegjs

I'm trying to build a simple parser with PEG.js.  I want the user to be able to input a series of keywords, with an optional "AND" between them, but I can't seem to get the optional and working.  It always expects it, even though I've marked it with a ? (zero or one).

Paste this grammar into http://pegjs.majda.cz/online:

```
parse = pair+

pair = p:word and? { return p }

word = w:char+ { return w.join(""); }

char = c:[^ \r\n\t] { return c; }

and = ws* 'and'i ws*

ws = [ \t]
```

My goal is to have either of these inputs parse into an array of ["foo", "bar"]:

```
foo bar
foo and bar
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, nevermind.  I figured it out.  It was because I made the optional whitespace preceding the 'and' as part of the **and** rule, so it expected the rest of the rule.  I just needed to move it out, into the **pair** rule, like so:

```
parse = pair+
pair  = p:word ws* and? { return p }
word  = w:char+ { return w.join(""); }
char  = c:[^ \r\n\t] { return c; }
and   = 'and'i ws*
ws    = [ \t]
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question, but seeing how it wasn't answered and someone might stumble upon it I'd like to submit my answer:

```
Program
    = w1:$Word _ wds:(_ "and"? _ w:$Word { return w; })* _  {
        wds.unshift(w1);
        return wds;
    }
Word 
    = [a-zA-Z]+
 _
    = [ ,\t]*
```

The "and" is optional and you can add as many words as you want. The parser will skip the "and"'s and return a list of the words. I took the liberty of removing commas.

You can try it out https://pegjs.org/online with a string like:

```
carlos, peter, vincent, thomas, and shirly
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer:

```
start
  = words

words
  = head:word tail:(and (word))* {
    var words = [head];
    tail.forEach(function (word) {
      word = word[1];
      words.push(word);
    })
    return words;
  }

and
  = ' and '
  / $' '+

word
  = $chars

chars 'chars'
  = [a-zA-Z0-9]+
```